# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Tags: android

Im trying to log a simple string from my database using firebase's docs guide yet I receive this error:
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

this is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("brands");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                Log.d("TAG", "Value is: " + value);
//;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }



}
```

Thanks for any sort of help!

logcat:

```
03-27 18:58:12.593 574-574/com.ofir.motoinfo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.ofir.motoinfo, PID: 574
                                                               com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaF(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.ofir.motoinfo.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:33)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the logcat but the error is at the line:

```
String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

You are requesting a `String` but the node in Firebase contains a `HashMap`. Make sure you are at the right node or that the data is formatted properly.

Comment: not really sure what a node is, added my logcat to the post.

Comment: Thanks for the logcat. What I mean by _node_ is your `DatabaseReference`, which points to a "node" in the "tree" structure that is Firebase's JSON database. Basically, log your `DatabaseReference` to make sure you are at the right place in your database. If so, you will also be able to see if the data at that reference is the data you want it to be. Something like `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Reference : " + myRef.toString() );` Then you can click the URL in your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I needed to add the childs to `DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference()`, as I was refering to the whole database.

Comment: Pleas show us how you add the child to complete this answer.